# installing multiarch-support - no installation candidate

Tags: kali-linux

This may be taged incorrectly but i belive my problem is kali specific.

When trying to install multiarch-support i am having an error that there is no installation candidate.

I have tried to tried to find solutions to this but what i have found is the manual download for ubuntu systems which do not work for me.

The bellow are reports which may help finding the problem.
Any help would be much aprechiated, thanks.

---

```
$ sudo apt-get install multiarch-support
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package multiarch-support is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'multiarch-support' has no installation candidate
```

/

```
# curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list                                                                                                
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    74  100    74    0     0    506      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   506
```

/

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Kali GNU/Linux 2021.2rc3 _Kali-last-snapshot_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 with firmware 20210528-08:52]/ kali-rolling contrib main non-free
deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
deb-src https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
#deb cdrom:[Kali GNU/Linux 2021.2rc3 _Kali-last-snapshot_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 with firmware 20210528-08:52]/ kali-rolling contrib main non-free

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

/

```
$ lsb_release -a                                                                                                                                                                                             
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:        2021.2
Codename:       kali-rolling
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you installing Kali Linux but switching away from the Kali
repositories to Ubuntu? The two might not be entirely compatible.
I do hope that you have not already updated some packages and
installed the wrong ones.

See the article
[Fix Kali Linux sources.list Repositories](https://kalitut.com/fix-kali-linux-sourceslist-repositories/).
The only repositories needed in `sources.list` are:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

Don't forget to run `sudo apt-get update`.

I don't know why you are making the effort of installing `multiarch`,
but if it's for installing another package, try now to install that
package first without `multiarch`.

You could also install
[multiarch-support](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/multiarch-support)
manually:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the slow responce, i dont work on this frequently. 
I was not awear that this repository was made for ubantu only.
I have tried what you have suggested but that has not worked for me presumerably due to its compatibility.

Essentialy, i am looking to get a repository so that i can make SQL queries to a microsoft database using a python script. Do you have any suggestions as to what may work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: A few sentences explaining these commands and what they are doing would go a long way towards making this a better answer than it is.